# Non-Paid Opportunities to Teach Coding to Children?

Tags: data.gov

A friend of mine is interested in non-paid opportunities to teach coding to children within an hour's drive of Baltimore. He was a professional game developer/ senior software engineer in Silicon Valley for six years and taught at both the undergraduate college and high school levels for many years.  He's currently enjoying teaching CoderDojo.

Does anyone know of opportunities in the DC-Baltimore area? Thanks so much for any advice and contacts!

Best,
Rebecca

Comment: Hi @Rebecca, sorry but this question isn't on-topic. I'd recommend looking through https://code.org/educate or contacting local groups.